# How to use Kotlin with a Bukkit/Spigot plugin and Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, bukkit

I am trying to use Kotlin for a Spigot plugin (for version 1.8.8), as I find Kotlin a lot more efficient to use. But, whenever I try and run the plugin, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
```

I have looked online, and it seems I need to shade the Kotlin jar file into my plugin, could anyone advise me how I would do that?

**UPDATE** After trying what was suggested below I still get the same error.
Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.31'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.2'
}

group 'me.graphicalcake95'
version '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'shadow'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly 'org.bukkit:bukkit:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    shadow "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java plugin library shading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956393/java-plugin-library-shading)

Comment: No, he is using Gradle, not Maven.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need to Shadow the Kotlin standard library into your plugin. Since you are using Gradle it can do this by using the [Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) which is similar to *Shade* but Shade is only for **Maven** so it won't be useful for you.

Using the Shadow plugin is straightforward. First you apply the plugin itself:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.0.0'
}
```

then you can configure Shadow:

```
shadowJar {
   baseName = 'shadow'
   classifier = null
   version = null
}
```

This will create a `shadow.jar` in your build folder when you build the project. After applying the shadow plugin you can `shadow` dependencies to be included in the fat jar:

```
dependencies {
  shadow "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I still get the same error, (I edited my original post to add the build.gradle)

Comment: Same as the original (`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics`)

Comment: Try adding the [kotlin-runtime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime) library as well. Did you check your `shadow.jar` whether it has Kotlin's code copied into it?

Comment: kotlin-runtime page says it is deprecated, so use kotlin-stdlib instead. Where would I find the shadow.jar? (it's not in build/libs). I've opened the finished jar file with 7zip, and the only packages are from my project (no org.jetbrains.kotlin etc)

Comment: I googled a bit more and some people said to add "build.dependsOn shadowJar" to the build.gradle. When I do this, I get a jar file for my project and also a shadow.jar in my build/libs folder, but when I open them both up as zip files, they just have my packages in (no Kotlin code)

Comment: For me it worked when I changed the dependency directive from shadow to compile, as specified in https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/how-to-use-kotlin-in-your-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Install [this plugin](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/kotlin-stdlib.80808/) on your spigot server
download the jar and place it in the plugins folder,
then follow the [documentation](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/kotlin-stdlib.80808/field?field=documentation)